# Why does my ITopologicalOperator Intersect result have incorrect area?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I have used ITopologicalOperator for getting common Area of two polygons but the result is not correct. May anyone please tell me how to get the common area of two features.

```
//Make Topological operator of geometry here
ITopologicalOperator pTopoOperator = (ITopologicalOperator)pGeometry;
//intersect of the above topo operator with another geometry
IGeometry pGeometry1 = pFeature1.Shape as IGeometry;
IGeometry pGeomResult = pTopoOperator.Intersect(pGeometry1, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry2Dimension);
//Typecasted to area viz. common area
IArea pCommonArea = (IArea)pGeomResult;
double dblCommonArea = pCommonArea.Area;
```

The Area value in dblCommonArea is not coming correct.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @PetrKrebs:Hi, Petr I have edited my post, with some ellaboration

Comment: How did you determine the area is not correct? Is it off by some small value or completely different to what you expect? Can you post the two polygons as WKT along with spatial reference information?

Comment: @PetrKrebs: Result is completely different from what we expected.Both are in GCS_WGS_1984 coordinate system these polygon are as follows; Polygon1-{(81.501,6.996),(82.001,6.99),(82.001,6.493),(81.501,6.503)};Polygon2-{(81.501,6.502),(81.603,6.559),(81.701,6.5081)}

Comment: The area will be calculated in the data source units, which will not make much sense for GCS_WGS_1984. You will need to project the data to a projected coordinate system before calculating the area.

Comment: @PetrKrebs :If I need area in meters then which coordinate system I must use.

Comment: @Nitin if you have a separate question, this site works better if you ask it separately, i.e. [Ask another question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You may also probably find the answer by just searching.

Comment: Is there a chance that the geometries are not good? Bowtie (hourglass) intrusions and reverse orientations can do odd things to areas and intersections. Use the ITopologicalOperator.IsKnownSimple = false followed by ITopologicalOperator.Simplify to fix these problems before intersecting.

Answer (score 1):

See if [`IAreaGeodetic`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000048m000000) gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to project spatial reference with feature geometry.
Try this code.

`pGeomResult.Project(pGeometry1.SpatialReference);`

`IGeometry pGeomResult = pTopoOperator.Intersect(pGeometry1, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry2Dimension);`

`// Calculate area for an intersect geomtry.
IArea pCommonArea = (IArea)pGeomResult;
double dblCommonArea = pCommonArea.Area;`